# Dojox DataChart with Legend

Tags: charts, dojo, legend

I want to make a Pie DataChart with Legend using a JSON file
My js code looks like this

```
    var store  = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore(
    { url:dojo.moduleUrl("dojox.charting", "file.json") 
});
makeObjects = function(){
    var chart1 = new dojox.charting.DataChart("test11111111", {
        type: dojox.charting.plot2d.Pie, // <-- chart type. Can be used Pie
        scroll:false,
        stretchToFit:true
    });
    var c = dojo.connect(chart1, "onData", function(){
        dojo.disconnect(c);
        new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({chart:chart1}, "legendPie");
    });
chart1.setStore(store2, {legend:"*"}, "ss_series");
chart1.render();
```

JSON file is like this

```
{ "items": [
    { "ss_series":[10126, 9803, 15965, 17290, 15667, 17762], 
      "legend":["Rome", "Paris", "Madrid", "Berlin", "London", "Dublin"]}
]}
```

The problem is that the Legend shows me also the percent from pie not the legend values
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about reformatting your data to:

```
"ss_series": [{y: 10126, legend: "Rome"}, {y: 9803, legend: "Paris"} , ... ]
```

this should do the trick?

Comment: No! Now the chart pie is empty and also the legend is empty. No values displayed.

Comment: Sorry replace "x" by "y" in my example is that working better?

Comment: Doesn't work. I change x by y, also i try to make it like this {x;1, y:10126, legend: "Rome"}, ... The same result, no data displayed.

Comment: I don't who what's happening but this is working fine for me. Editing original answer to use "y".